# Run Armbian in QEMU

Tags: windows, qemu

1. Has anyone runned Armbian in QEMU?
2. What is the command to run it?
3. From where to get kernel and which version?
4. Which version of Armbian to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, no, it's not supported. See [the response to a similar question in armbian forums](https://forum.armbian.com/index.php?/topic/541-armbian-vm-image-like-diet-pi/&tab=comments#comment-3547):

> That image is a normal X86 virtual image with, I assume, the same package base. I don't see much point in dealing with that ... but If you need that, install a base X86 Debian / Ubuntu system and https://github.com/igorpecovnik/lib/blob/second/deboostrap.sh#L138-L143 ... and you are close to Armbian. Special things are anyway very much hardware related, which aren't emulated.

Comment: @user29510 actually it is possible

Answer (score 3):

use qemu-system-arm on debian-buster and a specified cpu armv7 like H3 [NanoPi NEO Core-LTS](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=69&product_id=212) (same like orangepi)

before starting:

- download armbian image for H3
- unpack device tree (dtb) into folder `dtb`
- unpack ramdisk (`uInitrd-5.10.12-sunxi`) + kernel (`vmlinuz-5.10.12-sunxi`)

then run:

```
qemu-system-arm -m 1G,slots=3,maxmem=4G \
                            -machine type=orangepi-pc -cpu cortex-a7 -dtb dtb/sun8i-h3-nanopi-neo.dtb \
                            -smp 4 \
                            -kernel vmlinuz-5.10.12-sunxi -initrd uInitrd-5.10.12-sunxi -append "earlyprintk #loglevel=8 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0x1c28000,115200n8 console=ttyS0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1" \
                            -no-reboot -nographic -serial stdio -monitor none \
                            -hda Armbian_21.02.1_Nanopineo_buster_current_5.10.12.img \
                            -nic user,model=allwinner-sun8i-emac,hostfwd=tcp::50022-:22
```

boots up like charm :)

you can access the VM ssh port with `ssh -p 50022 localhost`

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. If you have an sd-card raw image of armbian, you just need to replace `-hda Armbian_21.02.1_Nanopineo_buster_current_5.10.12.img` with `-drive format=raw,file=sdcard.raw`